# Proving $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ is surjective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, where $x$ is a real number. Prove that $f$ maps $ \mathbb R$ onto $[1, \infty)$.

We must show that if $y \in Y$, then there exists an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$.

I am tempted to use the property $f(x) = y$ to replace $f(x)$ in  $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ with $y$ and solve $y = x^2 + 1$ for $x$. Would that be permissible what with the property $f(x) = y$ being in the conclusion  of the statement, rather than in the hypothesis and given conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y \in [1,\infty]$.  Then, choose $x=\sqrt{y-1}$, so that $f(x)=(\sqrt{y-1})^2+1=y-1+1=y$, and f is surjective.

Comment: How did you come up with $x$?

Comment: I just solved for for $x$ when $y=f(x)$.  The only thing you have to worry about is that you always have $y-1 \geq0$ so that you take the square root, which is fine because $y\in [1,\infty]$.

Comment: But you wouldn't write down that you solve for $x$ when $y = f(x)$ in the proof since that would be wrong, correct? If so, why would it be wrong to include that bit of info? Could it possibly be because it's not in the givens?

Comment: The proof is a game, in which you are given a $y \in [1,\infty]$, and you must find a real number $x$ such that $y=f(x)$.  Solving the equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ is a perfectly valid (and in most cases most direct) way to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Draw a rough sketch of f(x). It is an upward parabola with no real root. So, f(x) is an one-to-one function, but not onto, because co-domain of f(x)=R, whereas range of f(x)=Z(+). So, it is a surjective function.

Comment: The function $f$ is not one-to-one. For example, $f(1) = f(-1)$. It also is not surjective. ("Surjective" and "onto" are the same property.) And I have no idea how you bring $\mathbb{Z}_+$ into this.